# Reading H5T_STRING datatype via C++ HDF5 API

Tags: c++, hdf5

The dataset I have is:

```
DATASET "/test_dataset" {
   DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
      STRSIZE 18;
      STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLPAD;
      CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
      CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
   }
   DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 6 ) / ( 6 ) }
   DATA {
   (0): "Test_String_1\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000",
   (1): "Test_String_2\000\000\000\000", "Test_String_3",
   (3): "Test_String_4\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000",
   (4): "Test_String_5\000\000\000\000\000\000", "Test_String_6\000\000"
   }
}
```

I have been trying to read it as follows:

```
std::vector<std::string> temp_container;

const H5std_string DATASET_NAME("/test_dataset");
H5::DataSet dataset= h5_file.openDataSet(DATASET_NAME);
H5::DataSpace dataspace= dataset.getSpace();

ndims = dataspace.getSimpleExtentDims(dims_out, NULL);

temp_container.resize(dims_out[0]);

H5::StrType datatype= dataset.getStrType();

dataset.read(&temp_container[0], datatype, dataspace);
```

I also tried to read it via native H5::PredTypes, but I couldn't find any types that are related to string.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think variable `temp_container` declared as `std::vector<std::string>` can be used to store a variable-length string dataset. For a variable to be able to store such dataset it needs to be declared as `char **`.

Second, looking at the layout (i.e. dump) of the dataset above, it is a one-dimensional (size 6) of fixed-length (size 18) strings. Therefore, you need the variable to be declared as `char temp_container[6][18];`.

If you are not bound to a specific library take a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as it greatly alleviates you from HDF5 low-level details. So, using HDFql in C++, the dataset above can be read as follows (assume that it is stored in HDF5 file `test.h5`):

```
// declare variables
char temp_container[6][18];
char script[100];
int i;
int j;

// prepare script to read dataset 'test_dataset' (from HDF5 file test.h5) and populate variable 'temp_container' with it
sprintf(script, "SELECT FROM test.h5 test_dataset INTO MEMORY %d", HDFql::variableTransientRegister(temp_container));

// execute script
HDFql::execute(script);

// display content of variable 'temp_container'
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 18; j++)
    {
       std::cout << temp_container[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```